# does a repository with version control for rebol community scripts exist?

Tags: version-control, rebol

Adiu,

I use some scripts from http://www.rebol.org/script-index.r that I update regularly by using the librarian (http://www.rebol.org/download-librarian.r).

I just created an account on this site.

What is the current process, if one wants to improve a script (correct a bug, improve something, etc.)?

At some point, is it planned to migrate these scripts to github, so that code evolution will be easier?

(
PS: thanks for upvoting, so that I could chat in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red ;)
)

(
PPS: I corrected the question title; since Rebol3 sources, Red sources and many other Rebol-Red-related codes are on gi...ub, it would seem like a natural choice.
)

Comment: This does not appear to be an on-topic question here, as it is about the rebol community, not anything to do with code.

Comment: Well, the question has to do with correcting code from the rebol.org scripts repository.
I agree that @LouGit, you should have asked this on the Rebol and Red chat room, rather; but you seem to be a newbie with a low rep, so that you're unable to chat... yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that what I can do (or any one can do) is get a copy of rebol.org scripts, then put them on github, work on code, correct bugs, accept pull requests, etc.

But keeping rebol.org in sync with changes in github repository may be difficult. I don't know, I have never commited anything on rebol.org, so far.

Doing it one way, from rebol.org to github is certainly easy: get a cron to run librarian.r regularly, and then git diff, commit, push, etc.
But the other way will probably be more tricky.

Comment: So @pierre,  will you go ahead and fork rebol.org? Maybe it could break some users' habits on rebol.org?

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try. Not now: I'm in Cameroon now, in a hotel with a very strange connection, and I'll be gone soon, so... later.